# What is the correct way to set $scope values on page load in a service scenario?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some log in information that needs to be displayed in more than one place on an Angular.js backed UI. To this end, I have set up two controllers to return a service object created in app.factory. The reason this has been created as a service is to have the two controllers share the same model object.

What I would like to do is use ng-bind to send initial model values with the page content on initial page load (so as to avoid any delay while values are retrieved). I wondered if the html element value on `ng-bind` would update the `logInRegistrationUi` object in this example, but rather the element content is overwritten with the initialisation value ('example initial value') on the logInRegistrationUi object.

```
    var app = angular.module('fr', []);

    app.factory('logInRegistrationUiService', function() {


        var logInRegistrationUi = {

            logInRegistrationVisible: false,
            userLoggedIn: false,
            userEmailAddress: 'example initial value'
        };

        var logInRegistrationUiService = {

            logInRegistrationUi: logInRegistrationUi
        };

        return logInRegistrationUiService;
    });

    app.controller('logInRegistrationFormController', function ($scope, logInRegistrationUiService) {

        $scope.logInRegistrationUi = logInRegistrationUiService.logInRegistrationUi;

        console.log('logInRegistrationVisible (logInRegistrationFormController): ' + $scope.logInRegistrationUi.logInRegistrationVisible)
    });

    app.controller('logInRegistrationStatusController', function ($scope, logInRegistrationUiService) {

        $scope.logInRegistrationUi = logInRegistrationUiService.logInRegistrationUi;

        console.log('logInRegistrationVisible (logInRegistrationStatusController): ' + $scope.logInRegistrationUi.logInRegistrationVisible)
    });
```

The HTML source on page load - The ng-bind spans have literal content, in an attempt to have the element value update the service model.

```
<div ng-controller="logInRegistrationStatusController">
    ....            
    <span ng-bind="logInRegistrationUi.userEmailAddress">test@example.com</span>
    ....            

</div>

<div ng-controller="logInRegistrationFormController">
    ....            
    <span ng-bind="logInRegistrationUi.userEmailAddress">test@example.com</span>
    ....            

</div>
```

But instead of the service model object having the userEmailAddress, property updated, the text 'example initial value' is rendered as per initial service value.

How can I have the service property logInRegistrationUi.userEmailAddress updated from the ng-bind element content rather than vice versa?

**Update - Use of ng-init as per runTarm's answer produced the behaviour I was looking for, in a form that can be sent down with the page content on initial load**

```
<div ng-controller="logInRegistrationStatusController">
    ....            
    <span ng-bind="logInRegistrationUi.userEmailAddress"  ng-init="logInRegistrationUi.userEmailAddress = 'test@example.com'"></span>
    ....            

</div>

<div ng-controller="logInRegistrationFormController">
    ....            
    <span ng-bind="logInRegistrationUi.userEmailAddress">test@example.com</span>
    ....            

</div>
```

But instead of the service model object having the userEmailAddress, property updated, the text 'example initial value' is rendered as per initial service value.

How can I have the service property logInRegistrationUi.userEmailAddress updated from the ng-bind element content rather than vice versa?

Comment: The `ng-bind` works the opposite of what you are expected. It will update the html content to always be the same as value in the model, not vise versa. I'm not sure why you would like to do this, but you probably have to write a custom directive to do what you want.

Comment: were you expecting `ng-bind` to pass the existing text back to model? Not clear what expectations are. You probably should refer to the docs

Comment: @charlietfl Not so much an expectation, but yes that would have been useful in this scenario. That's not how it works and that's fine, but wondered how this scenario is usually dealt with, it must come up fairly reguarly I imagine.

Comment: Not clear what goal is then

Comment: The goal is to load the value of logInRegistrationUi from the HTML content in ng-bind element. That way, the data can be sent down with the initial HTML, rather that having to be loaded in a separate request - "How can I have the service property logInRegistrationUi.userEmailAddress updated from the ng-bind element content rather than vice versa?".

Comment: Can you be more clear?

Comment: Pretty sure that I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still couldn't imagine why in the world you would want to do the opposite of the `ng-bind`, but here are two ways to set the model value from a view.

1. You could write a custom directive like this:

   ```
   app.directive('reverseBind', function ($parse) {
     return {
       restrict: 'A',
       link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
         var setFn = $parse(attrs.reverseBind).assign;
         setFn(scope, element.text())
       }
     }
   })
   ```

   and in html:

   ```
   <span reverse-bind="logInRegistrationUi.userEmailAddress">test@example.com</span>
   ```
2. or just use the `ng-init`:

   ```
   <span ng-init="logInRegistrationUi.userEmailAddress = 'test@example.com'">test@example.com</span>
   ```

Comment: ng-init was what I was looking for, thank you for your answer. With regards to why - I did explain the use case in question and comments - that is to have the initial value preloaded with page content. If I'm really missing the point here then please explain - maybe I've misunderstood something about the Angular.js way of things, but this seems like a sensible thing to want to be able to do here.